# Surface described by an implicit function

Tags: numerical-methods, surfaces, implicit-function, meshing

I'm testing a surface mesh generator that takes a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and builds the surface described implicitly by $f(x,y,z)=0$. I already tested with a torus, a ball and an ellipse and things work perfectly well.

I'd like to come up with a "fancier" surface now, something which is not "standard" but that vary in space smoothly, but I can't think of any equation for this one. Does anybody has a good candidate?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Heart+Surface

Comment: Just did it with Maples plots[implicitplot3d] - but you need good resolution to get a nice representation of the heart

Comment: Thanks, amazing. Do you know where I can find more surfaces/equations like the one you wrote? :-) @RonnyLandsverk

Comment: Sum of random 3D gaussians with different scale and standard deviation

Comment: https://www.math.uh.edu/~molshan/tracefinite.html has a couple of interesting closed surfaces.